# Get Keyboard Toolbar Height

Tags: swift, keyboard, height, uitoolbar, notificationcenter

i have the same question as this :
[iPhone Keyboard with accessory view height problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26096253/iphone-keyboard-with-accessory-view-height-problems)

but the answer has no new solution and does not solve anything!

Answer (score 0):

I found a good solution [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23904848/how-can-i-add-a-toolbar-above-the-keyboard)

Made few changes and updated it to **swift 4.2**.

Few points to be mentioned

1. Created an outlet of textfield and bottom constraint from Storyboard to ViewController
2. Bottom constraint is used for moving the textfield up and down.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var inputField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var textFieldBottomContraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.setUpKeyBoardNotifications()
        self.addToolBarTo(uiElement: self.inputField)
    }
    func setUpKeyBoardNotifications()
    {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(self.keyboardNotification(notification:)),
                                               name: UIResponder.keyboardWillChangeFrameNotification,
                                               object: nil)
    }
    func addToolBarTo(uiElement element:UITextField)
    {
        let numberToolbar = UIToolbar(frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 45))
        numberToolbar.barStyle = .black
        numberToolbar.items = [
            UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.cancelAction)),
            UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil),
            UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.doneAction))]
        numberToolbar.sizeToFit()
       element.inputAccessoryView = numberToolbar

    }
    @objc func keyboardNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
            let endFrame = (userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue
            let endFrameY = endFrame?.origin.y ?? 0
            let duration:TimeInterval = (userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber)?.doubleValue ?? 0
            let animationCurveRawNSN = userInfo[UIResponder.keyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber
            let animationCurveRaw = animationCurveRawNSN?.uintValue ?? UIView.AnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut.rawValue
            let animationCurve:UIView.AnimationOptions = UIView.AnimationOptions(rawValue: animationCurveRaw)
            if endFrameY >= UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height {
                self.textFieldBottomContraint?.constant = 0.0
            } else {
                self.textFieldBottomContraint?.constant = endFrame?.size.height ?? 0.0
            }
            UIView.animate(withDuration: duration,
                           delay: TimeInterval(0),
                           options: animationCurve,
                           animations: { self.view.layoutIfNeeded() },
                           completion: nil)
        }
    }
    @objc func cancelAction()
    {
        self.inputField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
   @objc func doneAction()
    {
        self.inputField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    deinit {
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }
}
```